# Create regex for find statement that starts and ends with specific string, except a specific string

Tags: java, regex

I tried a lot but unable to find exact regex.

```
String str = "this cat is small. dog is pet anmial. this mouse is small.this toy is small. this is a cat and it's small. this is dog and it's small.  ";
Pattern ptr = Pattern.compile("this.*((?!(cat).)*).*small");
```

I want to extract strings, string starting with **this** ending with **small**
and should not contain **cat** anywhere between ,Its not getting the desire output using this regex.

my desire output is :

```
                this mouse is small
                this toy is small  
                this is dog and it's small
```

Comment: you can use `this.*?small` and you don't want to match the sentence with cat?

Comment: *my requirement is : this mouse is small this toy is small* **I do not understand how you will get this**

Comment: @PavneetSingh I don't think `.*?` is needed when using `String#matches()`, just `.*` will work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it seems to me OP wants the substrings not entire match

Comment: What do you plan to do with your pattern matching?  Just validate a sentence, or extract something?

Comment: i guess you need this `this\s(?!cat).*?small` if you want to extract strings

Comment: you have to be specific about  your question

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just out put should be: this (any number of time strings) small(end world) except cat word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String str = "this cat is small. dog is pet anmial. this mouse is small.this toy is small.";
Pattern ptr = Pattern.compile("this\\s(?!cat).*?small");
Matcher matcher=ptr.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Output:**

```
this mouse is small
this toy is small
```

`this\\s(?!cat).*?small`  : start with `this` and ends with `small`

`(?!cat)` : match if no cat is ahead

`.*?`   :  matches any character , as few times as possible

[**RegexDemo**](https://regex101.com/r/JaXNJE/1)

---

**Update :**

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/BGXSEV/1) `this((?!cat).)*?small`

Output :

```
this mouse is small
this toy is small
this is dog and it's small
```

`(?!cat).` : it will match any character till line break

Comment: @ScaryWombat haha thanks , finally got my first compliment :)

Comment: @PavneetSingh Sorry for late reply, after this could be any string multiple time, That's why I used ("this.*((?!(cat).)*).*small")   and you use (  "this\\s(?!cat).*?small"), why not use .* for multiple strings?

Comment: @Vinod `.*` is greedy mean , it will try to eat more and more character e.g instead of stopping at first `small`, `.*` will try to go ahead looking for next occurrence of `small` so to make it non-greedy we use `.*?` and try the link i added in my answer and try other variations , you will find the explanation side by side to guide you

Comment: so how get required result?

Comment: @Vinod you mean you want something else ? i am not quite following you , you can edit your question for clarity and with proper example of result and input

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
   String str = "this cat is small. dog is pet anmial. this mouse is    small.this toy is small.";
   Pattern .compile(^this.*\bsmall);
```

or

```
   Pattern .compile(^this.*small$);
```

Comment: you have edited your question so answer will be this((?!cat).)*?small

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
String input = "this mouse is small this toy is small";
boolean matches = input.matches("^This.*small$");
```

Comment: You don't need the anchors `^` and `$`, and besides that, your answer looks almost identical to mine.